# oauth2 get access token via db by supplied client id/secret for trusted 3rd party client

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm currently using "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel".

I'm making an api endpoint for a 3rd party trusted client and using the client_credentials grant.

now the thing is that access tokens tend to expire, so instead of giving the 3rd party user a access token, i would just supply  them with the client id/secret.

on my side i would do the following when they do a curl request...

```
SELECT      a.id,
            expire_time

FROM        oauth_clients as c

left join   oauth_sessions as s on s.client_id = c.id

left join   oauth_access_tokens as a on a.session_id = s.id

where       c.id = 'asfasasf'

            and c.secret =  'asfasfasfasf'

order by    s.id desc

limit       1;
```

... The above pretty much checks if there is an access token and expire time relating to the client id/secret. I'd pretty much just generate a new one if one didn't exist or if it expired. Then a couple lines down, do a curl on my side to the endpoint they were after with the given access_token on my side without them worrying about doing it.

I've tested it and it works, but is this kind of dodgy/bad to do?

tldr;

1. 3rd party client - goes to /api/endpoint with client id/secret
2. my server side (checks for access token in db relating to client id/secret)
3. generates if does not exists or is expired to use ...
4. 3rd party client endpoint api continues to use db selected access token
5. works

Is that a bad flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you did was take out a step for their convenience.

A lot of people would simply use an OAuth2 library they or someone else wrote and of course this wouldn't work because you don't have a standard OAuth2 system anymore.

You've effectively reused one token for everyone else who uses the client app and I am not convinced that's a good thing. Tokens expiring is for security issues, if someone steals a token, you can invalidate it and stop their access or it expires and that's it. Of course you don't have this issue as you're not actually passing tokens through.

This also means that you're now breaking other OAuth2 flows, many systems have a refresh token, that's gone as well. I guess it simplifies the client's life quite a bit but you can't say that you have an OAuth2 system anymore, because well, you don't.

The clients are the ones who need to deal with tokens and it's their job to decide how to store them and what to do when things expire. You wouldn't normally need to worry about it, but now you do since you actually store the client tokens on your side.

One other thing to consider is that you shifted the security concerns to your side. You are now responsible for the clients security. If someone gets access to your database then they can effectively impersonate all your clients forever more than likely without even you or the client knowing about it. From my point of view having tokens in a database is a bad idea and a security flaw especially when the client has no control over it.

Comment: Ah I see. I never thought having the access token in the db was bad, since it was pretty much designed like that from the authors. This is just for a single 3rd party trusted app as well. Would you be able suggest a more appropriate approach?

Comment: Oh just thought I'd mention that the access token actually does get regenerated on our side. This is suppose to be like a single purpose app api for a single user. Hopefully that changes things.

Comment: Sorry, last question. Would it be better forth client to just curl forth access token and then use the access token in a curl request right after the first one? This would mean the trusted client would generate a new access token on each request.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured I would go with the following:

1. the end consumer will be provided with the client id and secret.
2. since the end user is a trusted client machine-based, they will be using a client-credentials grant and only be retrieving a access token.
3. the end consumer can simply curl and retrieve the access token and then make another curl beneath the previous curl with the generated access token.
4. the last curl using the access token will then be able to access the protected resource.